# PhpMailer не отправляет письма когда активен ufw

Tags: php, phpmailer, ufw

Из соображений безопасности я использую ufw, в нём я открыл порты 80, 443 и 22.

Когда активен ufw, письма перестали отправляться.

Письма отправляются через php, используется библиотека PhpMailer.

```
> sudo ufw status

Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----

22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
587                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
465                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
25                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
587                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
465                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

```
> sudo ufw app list
Available applications:
  AIM
  Bonjour
  CIFS
  DNS
  Deluge
  IMAP
  IMAPS
  IPP
  KTorrent
  Kerberos Admin
  Kerberos Full
  Kerberos KDC
  Kerberos Password
  LDAP
  LDAPS
  LPD
  MSN
  MSN SSL
  Mail submission
  NFS
  Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS
  OpenSSH
  POP3
  POP3S
  PeopleNearby
  SMTP
  SSH
  Socks
  Telnet
  Transmission
  Transparent Proxy
  VNC
  WWW
  WWW Cache
  WWW Full
  WWW Secure
  XMPP
  Yahoo
  qBittorent
  svnserve
```

С того сервера пиггуется нормально:

```
> ping smtp.office365.com
PING DHR-efz.ms-acdc.office.com (52.97.139.178) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 52.97.139.178: icmp_seq=1 ttl=243 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from 52.97.139.178: icmp_seq=2 ttl=243 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from 52.97.139.178: icmp_seq=3 ttl=243 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from 52.97.139.178: icmp_seq=4 ttl=243 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from 52.97.139.178: icmp_seq=5 ttl=243 time=13.1 ms
64 bytes from 52.97.139.178: icmp_seq=6 ttl=243 time=12.7 ms
```

telnet подвисает...

```
> telnet smtp.office365.com 587
Trying 2603:1026:208:28::2...
Trying 2603:1026:208:86::2...
Trying 2603:1026:c03:2854::2...
```

Что нужно сделать с ufw, чтобы письма отправлялись? Порт какой-то открыть, но какой? Или что-то лишнее заблокировано? Что не так, понять не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй открыть для протокола SMTP  - 25 порт.
sudo ufw allow 25
Если не поможет то открой SSL SMTP 465,587 порты.

Comment: Это не решило. Обновлю основной вопрос с 25 портом.

Comment: Кстате в целях безопасности закрой 22 порт))))

Comment: Оба порта открыл - 465 и 587.

Comment: Самое интересное, что smtp.office365.com пингуется с того сервера нормально. 
Но если использовать ```> telnet smtp.office365.com 587``` то ответа нет когда ufw запущен.

Comment: Может используется IMAP? Открой 993 порт

Comment: Вот список портов: https://www.hesk.com/knowledgebase/?article=93